# why this reference is AppClassLoader rather than MyClassLoader when invoke loadClass method at the first time

Tags: java, jvm, classloader

I write myOwnClassLoader through extends the `classLoader` and override its **findClass** method. And meet a interesting problem:

Here is the code segment:

```
public class MyClassLoader extends ClassLoader {
    @Override
    public Class<?> findClass(String name) {
        byte[] bt = loadClassData(name);
        return defineClass(name, bt, 0, bt.length);
    }

    private byte[] loadClassData(String className) {
        ...
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException{
       MyClassLoader myClassLoader = new MyClassLoader();
       //Class<?> clazz = myClassLoader.findClass("com.classLoader.BMW");
       Class<?> clazz = myClassLoader.loadClass("com.classLoader.BMW");
       System.out.println(clazz.getClassLoader());//////////////////
    }
}
```

when execute

```
Class<?> clazz = myClassLoader.findClass("com.classLoader.BMW");
```

the output meet my expectation:
**output:**

```
com.classLoader.MyClassLoader@xxxxxx
```

**but** when execute

```
Class<?> clazz = myClassLoader.loadClass("com.classLoader.BMW");
```

the output go beyond my mind:
**output:**

```
sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@xxxx
```

**expect output**

```
com.classLoader.MyClassLoader@xxxxxx
```

here is code segment of **loadClass** method in `ClassLoader`

```
 Class<?> c = findLoadedClass(name);
 if (c == null) {
    long t0 = System.nanoTime();
    try {
        if (parent != null) {
            c = parent.loadClass(name, false);
            } else {
            c = findBootstrapClassOrNull(name);
        }
   .....
```

I debug it and find when we invoke `loadClass` at the ***first*** time the parent is **sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader@6aa8ceb6** that is to say **this** reference is **sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader** rather than **com.classLoader.MyClassLoader@xxxxxx** .

---

I search through internet and a blog [define own classLoader](http://stevex.blog.51cto.com/4300375/1579612) tell that

> it will set `AppClassLoader` as parent of `MyClassLoader` in default constructor.

I check it by

```
System.out.println(myClassLoader.getParent());
```

find the parent of *MyClassLoader* does be *AppClassLoader* how it achieve this, my default constructor do nothing and  was this achieve in *constructor method* of its parent class *ClassLoader*? I read its parent constructor and still cant firgure out.

Anyway it seemd this cant explain why the **this** is *AppClassLoader* rather than *MyClassLoader* when we first invoke **loadClass** method.
And I guess it is because that *the classLoader of MyClassLoader is `AppClassLoader` but it is just a intuition I have no gist.

Everything will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it’s all documented:

[`ClassLoader()` constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#ClassLoader--):

> Creates a new class loader using the `ClassLoader` returned by the method `getSystemClassLoader()` as the parent class loader.

[`loadClass(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#loadClass-java.lang.String-):

> Loads the class with the specified binary name. … Invoking this method is equivalent to invoking `loadClass(name, false)`.

[`loadClass(String,boolean-)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#loadClass-java.lang.String-boolean-):

> Loads the class with the specified binary name. The default implementation of this method searches for classes in the following order:
>
> 1. Invoke `findLoadedClass(String)` to check if the class has already been loaded.
> 2. Invoke the `loadClass` method on the parent class loader. If the parent is `null` the class loader built-in to the virtual machine is used, instead.
> 3. Invoke the `findClass(String)` method to find the class.
>
> If the class was found using the above steps, and the `resolve` flag is true, this method will then invoke the `resolveClass(Class)` method on the resulting `Class` object.
>
> Subclasses of `ClassLoader` are encouraged to override `findClass(String)`, rather than this method.

This is also mentioned in the [class documentation of `ClassLoader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/lang/ClassLoader.html):

> The `ClassLoader` class uses a delegation model to search for classes and resources. Each instance of `ClassLoader` has an associated parent class loader. When requested to find a class or resource, a `ClassLoader` instance will delegate the search for the class or resource to its parent class loader before attempting to find the class or resource itself. The virtual machine's built-in class loader, called the "bootstrap class loader", does not itself have a parent but may serve as the parent of a `ClassLoader` instance.

This logic ensures clean scoping, i.e. classes of the parent scope don’t refer to classes of a sub scope, and that there are no conflicts between classes of the same qualified name, but defined by different class loaders. Such classes may still exist in distinct scopes, but not in nested scopes. But class loaders are not enforced to follow this rule. The delegation model was introduced with Java 2.